# Hypothesis space of regression/classification tree

Tags: cart

I'm wondering how to exactly define the hypothesis space of a tree.

For simplicity start with a regression tree

$f(x) = \sum_{m=1}^Mc_m\mathbb{I}(x \in R_m)$

Where $c_m$ are the ( $M$ ) constant leaves and $R_m$ the hyperrectangles/boxes of the terminal regions.

I think you could write the hypothesis space like this:

$H = \{\sum_{m=1}^Mc_mI(x \in R_m)| c_m \in \mathbb{R}, R_m = \text{box}_m(\mathcal{X})\quad \forall m=1,\dots,M \}$

where $R_m$ are boxes, axis parallel to $\mathcal{X}$ such that

$\bigcup_{m=1,\dots,M}R_m = \mathcal{X}$ and

$R_m \cap R_{m'} = \emptyset \quad \forall m \ne m'$.

Some questions:

1) Is the above definition correct?

2) Is there a reference where this hypothesis space is explicitly defined?

3) Can I write it simpler?

4) Is it possible to write this definition down fully parametric, i.e.,  depending on the splits instead of the terminal boxes?

5) I think the above statement only works for a fully numeric $\mathcal{X}$, since I'm not sure how to define boxes if $x_j$ can be categorical.